# In Spring MongoDB update, MonogDB doc replaced/lost fields, becomes empty, oplog "o" for this update has no $set, $unset, has only objectId as in "o2"

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-oplog

### Context:

- Spring Data MongoDB is used and updating a document caused the following issue.

### Issue :

After an update operation performed, document in collection lost all the data and kept only `ObjectId` in it.

Checking the `oplog` entry found an unusual value, understand that the `o2`field `ObjectId` says the object to be updated and `o`field says about operations being performed/updated.

In this particular instance `o2`field has the expected value, but `o` field also has the same value instead of the update operation details to be done.

### Question :

Any idea when can we expect such an `oplog` as mentioned below without `$set` or `$unset` for update operations ?

After this operation, actual document with `ObjectId` in collection lost all the fields except `ObjectId`.

```
{
        "ts" : Timestamp(1596778564, 9),
        "t" : NumberLong(7),
        "h" : NumberLong(0),
        "v" : 2,
        "op" : "u",
        "ns" : "db.collectionName",
        "ui" : UUID("2947862a-8fb7-4342-87d1-a0ab5f8bc0bd"),
        "o2" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5f27e94e0174081a3feb5c6b")
        },
        "wall" : ISODate("2020-08-07T05:36:04.402Z"),
        "lsid" : {
                "id" : UUID("cbd4b90f-1bff-4ad1-b4e2-4c286fc25450"),
                "uid" : BinData(0,"47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=")
        },
        "txnNumber" : NumberLong(1269),
        "stmtId" : 0,
        "prevOpTime" : {
                "ts" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                "t" : NumberLong(-1)
        },
        "o" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5f27e94e0174081a3feb5c6b")
        }
}
```

The update `oplog` for the same object few milliseconds ago is given below. Which has the right set of operations.

```
{
        "ts" : Timestamp(1596778564, 8),
        "t" : NumberLong(7),
        "h" : NumberLong(0),
        "v" : 2,
        "op" : "u",
        "ns" : "db.collectionName",
        "ui" : UUID("2947862a-8fb7-4342-87d1-a0ab5f8bc0bd"),
        "o2" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5f27e94e0174081a3feb5c6b")
        },
        "wall" : ISODate("2020-08-07T05:36:04.398Z"),
        "lsid" : {
                "id" : UUID("cbd4b90f-1bff-4ad1-b4e2-4c286fc25450"),
                "uid" : BinData(0,"47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=")
        },
        "txnNumber" : NumberLong(1268),
        "stmtId" : 0,
        "prevOpTime" : {
                "ts" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                "t" : NumberLong(-1)
        },
        "o" : {
                "$v" : 1,
                "$set" : {
                        .....
                       .......
                      ......... //All the values to be updated
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: You had a query that set the document to {_id: 'foo'} ?

Comment: No, able to set the values for the document, but in some random update operation entire fields in document is lost with ObjectId alone left. Checking in oplog found that there is no "$set" or "$update" operation in update operation. Wondering when this could be possible.

Comment: See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/. You are providing the "replacement document".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope it helps some one facing in Spring-MongoDB as well, as I did.

Tried following code, It happens when `update` used in `mongoTemplate.updateFirst` isn't set with any value while calling. If the line `update.set` is uncommented works fine. When nothing is set in update, it took it as replacement document.

```
@Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        customerRepository.deleteAll();

        customerRepository.save(new Customer("Bob","S"));
        customerRepository.save(new Customer("Alice","Smith"));

        findAll();

        Update update = new Update();
//      update.set("firstName", "Bobby");

        Query query = Query.query(Criteria.where("lastName").is("S"));
        mongoTemplate.updateFirst(query, update, "customer");

        findAll();
    }
```

Further checking our code, found that `set` is called on an `update` based on CONDITION IF values to set are available or not, it seems to working fine as long as the values are available and `set` is called on `update`. If the values are not available to set, `set` is not called on `Update` to set the values, which took it as replacement and replaced the entire document in collection.

Comment: Since there was no problem with oplog this question seems misleading.

Comment: Updated the question with relevant context.

Answer (score 0):

One of your applications is providing a "replacement document" as described in https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/. The replacement document consists of the _id only which removes the other fields. There is nothing out of ordinary about the oplog entry you quoted.

Comment: Tried following code, It happens when 'update' used in 'updateFirst' isn't set with any value while calling. If "update.set" is uncommented works fine. When no update is set, it took it as replacement document.
@Override
 public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
  customerRepository.save(new Customer("Bob","S"));
  customerRepository.save(new Customer("Alice","Smith"));
  Update update = new Update();
//  update.set("firstName", "Bobby");
  Query query = Query.query(Criteria.where("lastName").is("S"));
  mongoTemplate.updateFirst(query, update, "customer");
  findAll();
 }